# Verificar duas ou mais ocorrências de elemento em lista (lambda/linq)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho a seguinte `list<t>`

```
listCard;
```

dentro dela tenho os seguintes valores:

```
[0]:7720890002560
[1]:7720890002560
[2]:7777777002560
[3]:7720890002560
[4]:7720444402560
[5]:7720777002560
[6]:7728888802560
[7]:7727777702560
```

preciso verificar se **existe mais de uma ocorrência** de um determinado valor, por exemplo, 7720890002560 (no meu exemplo acima possuo 2 ocorrências desse valor)

só para nota de esclarecimento eu vou pegar o retorno tipo

```
if (ExisteMaisQueUm) continue;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido desta forma:

```
if (listCard.Count(_ => _.ToString().Equals(card)) > 1) continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma de resolver:

```
if (listCard.Count(x => x == card) > 1) continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja esta forma usando o linq por sintaxe de método:

```
var listCard = new List<string>
{
    "7720890002560",
    "7720890002560",
    "7777777002560",
    "7720890002560",
    "7720444402560",
    "7720777002560",
    "7728888802560",
    "7727777702560"
};

var valoresRepedidos = listCard.GroupBy(s => s).SelectMany(group => group.Skip(1)).ToList();

WriteLine($"Ocorrencias: {valoresRepedidos.Count()}\n");

valoresRepedidos.ForEach(s => WriteLine(s));
```

Saída:

> Ocorrencias: 2
>
> 7720890002560
>   7720890002560

Caso não possuir nenhum valor repetido a variavel `valoresRepedidos` vai possuir 0 itens.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811464/how-to-get-duplicate-items-from-a-list-using-linq).